# Caching is not being clear on site restart

Tags: web-services, caching, iis-6, appdomain

I am using singleton pattern to load some configurations which are in database. If I add some new configurations in database and restart the webservice then it doesn't load those settings. For this If I do restart the IIS server then it works fine.

I am not sure where does it reside?Is it loaded in App Domain and I need to restart AppDomain also? I m not clear why this is happening. Because if I restart the service from IIS it should clear all the information from app domain too but not happening.

Comment: You mention caching on the question title, however, later on refer to settings? Could you please expand your question some more? Possibly with sample source code pin-pointing the problem better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stopping the Website will only stop accepting request while keeping your application in the same state. Worker process won't stop.

To restart the worker process, thus flushing the memory, you need to recycle the Application Pool.

[You can read more about it](http://mvolo.com/starting-stopping-and-recycling-iis-70-web-sites-and-application-pools).